# Unable to find the requested Boost libraries

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake

Platform:macOS High Sierra

Hello,
I tried to use the method ***Building from source*** to install [RDkit](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit), there is something wrong when I entered `cmake ..`,the terminal shows that

> CMake Warning at 
>   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1723 (message):
>     No header defined for python-py36; skipping header check
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:202 (find_package)
>
> CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2044 (message):
>     Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.67.0
>
> Boost include path: /usr/local/include
>
> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> boost_python
>
> No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
>   directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
>     Boost.

But I have added /usr/local/Cellar/boost/lib and /usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/lib to the ~/.bash_profile.
My ~/.bash_profile is written like this:

> export RDBASE=/Users/wangzhicheng/Software/RDkit/rdkit-Release_2018_03_3
>
> export PYTHONPATH=$RDBASE
>
> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$RDBASE/lib:/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib:/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.67.0/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.67.0_1/lib
>
> export PATH="/Users/wangzhicheng/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

By the way, I had already installed boost, boost-python3 by homebrew.

So where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution to this problem.

The reason for the problem cmake want to find libboost_python3.dylib in your library folder but in fact this file is called libboost_python3x.dylib(x is depended on your python version), so you just need to type following command in your terminal:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s libboost_python3x.dylib libboost_python3.dylib
```

and you can solve this error!